# How to view raw json that my chatbot receives?

Tags: python, json, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

```
{  
       "object":"page",
       "entry":[  
          {  
             "id":"255502108230287",
             "time":1502382558816,
             "messaging":[  
                {  
                   "sender":{  
                      "id":"1573650332660059"
                   },
                   "recipient":{  
                      "id":"255502108230287"
                   },
                   "timestamp":1502381982109,
                   "message":{  
                      "mid":"mid.$cAACylCZ7gBtj_jcJnVdzPHBbHOTC",
                      "seq":302583,
                      "text":"hii",
                      "nlp":{  
                         "entities":{  
                            "location":[  
                               {  
                                  "suggested":true,
                                  "confidence":0.97574394420685,
                                  "value":"hii",
                                  "type":"value"
                               }
                            ],
                            "greetings":[  
                               {  
                                  "confidence":0.71404528798453,
                                  "value":"true"
                               }
                            ]
                         }
                      }
                   }
                }
             ]
          }
       ]
    }
```

I am hosting Messenger's webhook in Heroku.To analyze the text, I need to look at the original json from the Facebook server when webhook receives a message from the user. Above json is an example.If I can not see it on Heroku, I can also host webhook on my local server. Is there any way to do this? Here's my webhook code: https://github.com/EdgeGIT/DasanAssistant/blob/master/app.py or https://github.com/EdgeGIT/dasangeupsik/blob/master/index.js
Thank you very much.

Comment: You can use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) for hosting webhook on your local server.

Comment: If I host it locally, can I view it?

Comment: Not sure what you want but you can add a debug log (like `print output` ) in your code.

Comment: yausername is right, adding a debug log like `print(output)` should be enough to allow you to view the raw JSON response data. You should be able to see these logs in your Heroku console too. Did you manage to get this to work?